# Moodle Installation on ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, moodle

I have tried to download the moodle code for installing in ubuntu as explained at,

[Step 4 here](https://docs.moodle.org/28/en/Step-by-step_Installation_Guide_for_Ubuntu#Step_4:_Download_Moodle)

When i try to do,

```
sudo git clone git://git.moodle.org/moodle.git
```

I get the following error,

```
sudo git clone git://git.moodle.org/moodle.git
Cloning into 'moodle'...
fatal: unable to connect to git.moodle.org:
git.moodle.org: No address associated with hostname
```

Please help me resolving this

Comment: moodle has a mirror repository https://github.com/moodle/moodle you can clone from here

Comment: Can you access github from web?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try the github mirror?

```
git clone https://github.com/moodle/moodle.git
```

If that doesn't work then its a problem with the internet connection.

You don't need to use sudo.